# raspberry multiple magnetix switches

Tags: electronics, switches

I have a Pi 2 and I would like to monitor the state of 3 magnetic switches. All of them are in close distance, no more than 3m of cabling for each one of them. How can I connect them to monitor their current state (open/closed)? 
The reed switches are Uxcell MC-38's:

[https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Window-Sensor-Magnetic-Recessed/dp/B00HR8CT8E/ref=br_lf_m_s6wxaka957nr7r3_img?_encoding=UTF8&s=hi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HR8CT8E)

Comment: No one can help you unless you tell us exactly what the "magnetic switches" are -- preferably with a link to a product page.

Comment: A magnetic door switch is one of the following. https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Window-Sensor-Magnetic-Recessed/dp/B00HR8CT8E/ref=br_lf_m_s6wxaka957nr7r3_img?_encoding=UTF8&s=hi

Comment: In future edit information into the question ;)